# SQL query to get records with multiple occurance of specific conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hope someone can help me with this. I am not great at SQL.

I want to get list of employees who has address in both USA and UK(England/Scotland)

| Employee | Address |
| --- | --- |
| Emp1 | England |
| Emp1 | England |
| Emp1 | Scotland |
| Emp2 | US |
| Emp2 | US |
| Emp2 | Canada |
| Emp3 | Scotland |
| Emp3 | US |
| Emp3 | Scotland |
| Emp3 | US |
| Emp3 | India |

There can be multiple countries but i want to focus on US and UK(which includes both England and Scotland) only.

Comment: *both USA and UK(England/Scotland)* - this is ambiguous - do you mean in all 3 or US and one of either England or Scotland?

Comment: But the UK includes Wales and Northern Ireland...

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table with itself (one instance for US, one instance for UK) to find rows you want. For example:

```
select distinct us.employee
from t us
join t uk on uk.employee = us.employee
where us.address = 'US'
  and uk.address in ('England', 'Scotland')
```

Alternatively, you can use `EXISTS` to filter out rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregation this is pretty straight forward.

```
Select Employee
from YourTable
where Address in ('England', 'Scotland')
group by Employee
having count(distinct Address) = 2
```